# Only loading first 5 seconds of a MP3 File

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer

I have a MP3 file on my server that is 30 seconds long. I only want to play the first 5 seconds as a "preview".

Currently I am loading the full MP3 and then playing the file through AVAudioPlayer for the first 5 seconds. The issue I have with this is if the user is not on a WiFi network, this eventually can become expensive in terms of the user's data plan. I thought of finding a way to cut off downloading of the file after x amount (which I would have to calculate) of data is sent but not sure if this would be the right solution.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stream audio, try [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html).

You can use NStimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:numberOfSeconds
    target:self
    selector:@selector(stopAudio)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
```

When you start streaming just [fire](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire) timer and in `stopAudio` method stop streaming audio after `numberOfSeconds` seconds.

Comment: I am using similar code for stopping the audio but did not know about AVPlayer.  Let me try this out to make sure I do not have any more questions before approving answer. Thank you as well!

Comment: If the user has a fast + expensive phone plan, it is quite possible that all 30 seconds are downloaded within 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm not to worried about how fast something is downloaded/streamed.  @gnasher729 Just the application I am creating has lots of "previews" being played at once and the current way downloaded the whole file where as I rather just stream the first 5 seconds instead saving the user data.  I found this out the hard way because I went over my data plan twice before finding this was one of the main causes =P

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, AVA is not the best for streaming audio :

[Streaming with an AVAudioplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312699/streaming-with-an-avaudioplayer)

Hope it helps